# Prim's Algorithm in C producing incorrect output

Tags: c, makefile, prims-algorithm

I've been tasked with implementing Prim's algorithm to find the MCST using an adjacency matrix to represent the graph, and a struct to hold the MCST.  The program takes in a file input, applies the algorithm and then outputs the minimum cost spanning tree.  I got the program to take a file input and produce output, but the values I am getting are incorrect and look like dummy values to me.

My assumption is that the error occurs in either how I am storing the file input in my array, or in the algorithm itself.  I've spent a good 12-15 hours troubleshooting this issue and am hoping someone can provide insight.  The program is written in C and compiled with make in the format `./a6 <file>`.  I take and store the file input in my main() and then the methods are used in the order they are called.  Below is an example my professor provided.  The first line contains info about the vertices being entered and the remaining lines contain the actual data itself.

```
input:
6 10 0 <<--(size, edges, start)
0 1 16 <<--(from, to, weight)
0 5 21
0 4 19
1 2 5
1 3 6
1 5 11
2 3 10
3 4 18
3 5 14
4 5 33
output:
0 1 16 <<--(first edge)
1 2 5
1 3 6
1 5 11
3 4 18
total cost: 56
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MAX */

#define N 10 /* max matrix size is 10 x 10 */
#define INF 9999

int cost =  0;
typedef struct lnode {
    int fromv;
    int tov;
    int weight;
    struct lnode *next;
} lnode;

int insertnode(lnode **lst, int from, int to, int wt);
void prims(int amtrx[][N],int n, lnode **lst);
void printpaths(lnode **lst);
void freelist(lnode **lst);
int isValid(int a, int b, int select[]);

int insertnode(lnode **lst, int from, int to, int wt){
    lnode *newnode;
    newnode = (lnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));

    newnode->fromv = from;
    newnode->tov = to;
    newnode->weight = wt;
    newnode->next=NULL;

    if(*lst == NULL){
        newnode -> next = *lst;
        *lst = newnode;
    } else {

        lnode *current;
        current = *lst;
        while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
        newnode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newnode;
    }

    return 1; 
}

int isValid(int a, int b, int select[]){
    if(a == b) return 0;
    if(select[a] == 0 && select[b] == 0) return 0;
    else if (select[a] == 1 && select[b] == 1) return 0;
    return 1;
}


void prims(int amtrx[][N], int n, lnode **lst){
    int i, j, row, col, edges_seen, min;
    int select[N] = {0};
    edges_seen = 0;
    select[n] = 1;
    while(edges_seen < N-1){
        min = INF;
        row = -1;
        col = -1;
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
                if(amtrx[i][j] < min) {
                    if(isValid(i, j, select) == 1){
                        min = amtrx[i][j];
                        row = i;
                        col = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(row != -1 && col != -1){
            select[col] = 1;
            select[row] = 1;
            cost = cost + min;
            insertnode(lst, row, col, min);
            edges_seen++;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            printf("%3d", select[i]);
        }
        puts("\n\n");
    }

}

void printpaths(lnode **lst){
    lnode *current;
    current = *lst;
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%4i  ",current->fromv);
        printf("%4i  ", current->tov);
        printf("%4i \n", current->weight);

        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\ntotal cost: %4i\n", cost);
}


void freelist(lnode **lst) {
    lnode *temp = NULL;
    while(*lst != NULL)
    {
        temp = *lst;
        *lst = (*lst)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}




int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    lnode *lst;
    lst = (lnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
    int i, j, nsz, nedg, fr, to, vtx, wt;
    vtx = 1111;
    nedg = 999;
    nsz = 100;
    fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &nsz, &nedg, &vtx);
    int amtrx[nsz][N];

    for(i = 0; i < nsz; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < nsz; j++){
                    amtrx[i][j] = INF;
            }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < nedg; i++){
        fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &fr, &to, &wt);
        amtrx[fr][to] = wt;
        amtrx[to][fr] = wt;
    }

    fclose(f);
    prims(amtrx, vtx, &lst);
    printpaths(&lst);
    freelist(&lst);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: regarding: `FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");`  1) never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user entered the expected command line parameters.  2) when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful, call `perror( "fopen failed" )` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `lst = (lnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &nsz, &nedg, &vtx);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers (in this case 3).   Any value returned, other than 3, indicates an error occurred, including EOF

Comment: OT: for ease of readabiltiy and understanding:  please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT:  regarding the declaration of `i` and the two `for()` statements.  It is good programming practice to limit the 'scope' of variables.  Suggest removing the the declaration of `i` and modifying the `for()` statements similar to: `for( int i=0;  i < nsz; i++){`

Comment: OT: regarding: `void printpaths(lnode **lst){`  Why pass `lst` as a double pointer, when the body of the function does not modify the contents of `lst`?

Comment: Thank you for your input! The reason that I'm casting for ```lst``` , passing a double pointer, have more than one statement per line,, the way I used ```fscanf()```,  and having a larger scope for ```i``` than necessary is because my professor is very picky when grading code and we are marked down if we do not do things the way he wants. And, those are all things he expected for this project.  Thank you for the suggestion of using a check for arguments and for taking the time to look at my code